# Expand command read from file

Tags: macros, conditionals, expansion, programming, automation

I have a file, that contains a list of latex commands each command per line. Now I want to read this file line per line and execute/expand the macros automatically. I tried the following but this only prints out the command instead of executing it.

```
\makeatletter
\newread\myread
\newcount\linecnt
\openin\myread=testfile.tex
\@whilesw\unless\ifeof\myread\fi{%
  \advance\linecnt by \@ne
  \readline\myread to \line
  \line
}
\makeatother
```

How can I fix this? I don't think that there is something like `\forceexpand\line`. How can I make this to ignore comments in `testfile.tex`?

**Edit**:

As Joseph Wright pointed out in a comment, I should use `\read` instead of `\readline`. This also ignores comments but it doesn't solve my comment problem completely. To illustrate this, here is my original motivation for this question:

I wanted to test multiple fonts in xelatex in different documents (which where put together via pdfpages in a later step, but this is too complicated and doesn't matter here). However for this situation I wanted to have a single file with the list of fonts I wanted to try, like this (`testfile.tex`):

```
\setmainfont{font1}
%\setmainfont{font2}
\setmainfont{font3}
```

Then I have a document file, something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}

\newcommand{\testtext}{Some Text}

\begin{document}
    \makeatletter
    \newread\myread
    \newcount\linecnt
    \openin\myread=testfile.tex
    \@whilesw\unless\ifeof\myread\fi{%
      \advance\linecnt by \@ne
      \read\myread to \line
      \line
      \testtext
      \newline %\newpage
    }
    \makeatother
\end{document}
```

This should output the content of `\testtext` twice, one time with font1 and one time with font3, the commented entry with font2 should be ignored completely (instead of printing the text with font1 twice). So I should detect somehow in the loop if the line was a comment and don't execute `\testtext` and `\newline` in this case.

Comment: You do know that you are using `\readline` rather than `\read`, don't you? `\readline` is deliberately verbatim-like.

Comment: Thanks, that solves the problem. Since I want to print some text after `\line` it would be great to explicitely detect if the line in testfile.tex was a comment or not, is this possible?

Comment: The `\read` primitive applies normal category codes, so you will see nothing if the line is a comment. An alternative approach is to use `\readline` and `\scantokens`: what we need is a bit more context to see what you actually want to do. Could you edit in a small demo file and required output?

Comment: If you read each command and execute it, how do you want the behaviour to differ from just using `\input` ?

Answer (score 10):

If the `%` comes first in the line you want to omit, just test whether the line just read is empty; setting `\endlinechar` to –1 while reading the file avoids the appended end of line that becomes a space or `\par`.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.tst}
\fontspec{Linux Libertine O}
%\fontspec{Old Standard}
\fontspec{TeX Gyre Cursor}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newcommand{\testtext}{Some Text \fontname\font}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\newread\myread
\newcount\linecnt
\begingroup\endlinechar=\m@ne
\openin\myread=\jobname.tst
\loop\unless\ifeof\myread
  \advance\linecnt by \@ne
  \read\myread to \line
  \ifx\line\@empty\else
    {(\number\linecnt) \line\testtext}%
    \par %\newpage
  \fi
\repeat
\endgroup
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

[image]

Using `\loop...\repeat` is easier than `\@whilesw`.

Answer (score 9):

Also the deleted idea of David Carlisle with `\input{testfile}` works. The data does already contain TeX macro markup. All we need is to define the macro to do the job we want to do. The following modifies [egreg's example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/116174/16967):

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.tst}
\fontspec{DejaVu Sans}
\fontspec{Linux Libertine O}
%\fontspec{Old Standard}
\fontspec{TeX Gyre Cursor}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newcommand{\testtext}{Some Text}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
  \let\OrgFontSpec\fontspec
  \renewcommand*{\fontspec}[2][]{%
    (\the\inputlineno) %
    \begingroup
      \OrgFontSpec[{#1}]{#2}%
      \testtext\ [#2] \fontname\font
    \endgroup
    \par
    % \newpage
  }%
  \input{\jobname.tst}%
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]