# Concatenating commands with arguments in a macro?

Tags: macros, loops

I want to read some lines from a text file, wrap a "style" which in this case is `\texttt` around each line, and as such concatenate it to a macro that I can use in the document. I came up with this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents} % tlmgr install filecontents

\begin{filecontents*}{test-2.txt}
some more
words in
here so as
to eventually
print
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{xstring}

\def\totcontent{}
\def\mystyle#1{\texttt{#1}}

% related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116078/expand-command-read-from-file
\newread\myread
\makeatletter
\immediate\openin\myread=test-2.txt
\@whilesw\unless\ifeof\myread\fi{%
  \readline\myread t\expandafter o\csname tmpline\endcsname %
  \typeout{Got tmpline: \tmpline} %
  \StrGobbleRight{\tmpline}{1}[\tmpline] % remove the ^^M newline (last 1 char)
  \ifx\tmpline\empty\else %
    %\edef\totcontent{\totcontent, \tmpline} % works without mystyle
    %\edef\totcontent{\totcontent, \mystyle{\tmpline}} % fail, breaks
    % via http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74709/2595:
    \g@addto@macro\totcontent{, \mystyle{\tmpline}} % compiles, but no content in output
  \fi %
}
\immediate\closein\myread
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\typeout{totcontent is: \totcontent.}

I got this: \totcontent.

\end{document}
```

In all cases, I get this for the file reading:

```
Got tmpline: some more^^M
Got tmpline: words in^^M
Got tmpline: here so as^^M
Got tmpline: to eventually^^M
Got tmpline: print^^M
Got tmpline: ^^M
```

... which means the line ending is kept, so I remove the character at the end of the "string" with `xstring`'s `\StrGobbleRight`.

The first case, `\edef\totcontent{\totcontent, \tmpline}` works fine, but has no style - the typeout then says:

```
totcontent is: , some more, words in, here so as, to eventually, print.
```

The second case, `\edef\totcontent{\totcontent, \mystyle{\tmpline}}`, breaks completely:

```
! Argument of \@xs@StrGobbleRight has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.30 }
```

Here I intended on using `\mystyle` as a placeholder macro - expecting that in concatenation `\edef`s it would expand down to `\texttt` tokens, which I remember are `\protect`ed, and so won't expand further. Obviously, that didn't work.

The third case, `\g@addto@macro\totcontent{, \mystyle{\tmpline}}` actually does compile, but gives:

```
totcontent is: , \texttt {}, \texttt {}, \texttt {}, \texttt {}, \texttt {}.
```

... which is close, but still not what I wanted (I wanted the `\texttt` to be populated by the respective arguments from the loop).

So, how can I perform the concatenation, so in the end I end up with:

```
totcontent is: , \texttt {some more}, \texttt {words in}, \texttt {here so as}, \texttt {to eventually}, \texttt {print}.
```

... such that it would also typeset as we'd expect it to?

---

```
As per comments, example with `\read`:

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents} % tlmgr install filecontents

\begin{filecontents*}{test-2.txt}
some more
words in
here so as
to eventually
print
\end{filecontents*}

\def\totcontent{}
\def\mystyle#1{\texttt{#1}}

\newread\myread
\makeatletter
\immediate\openin\myread=test-2.txt
\@whilesw\unless\ifeof\myread\fi{%
  \read\myread to \tmpline %
  \typeout{Got tmpline: \tmpline} %
%   \ifx\tmpline\empty\else %
  \ifx\tmpline\par\else %
    %\edef\totcontent{\totcontent, \tmpline} % works without mystyle
    %\edef\totcontent{\totcontent, \mystyle{\tmpline}} % fail, breaks
    \g@addto@macro\totcontent{, \mystyle{\tmpline}} % compiles, but no content in output
  \fi %
}
\immediate\closein\myread
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\typeout{totcontent is: \totcontent.}

I got this: \totcontent.

\end{document}
```

Prints:

```
Got tmpline: some more 
Got tmpline: words in 
Got tmpline: here so as 
Got tmpline: to eventually 
Got tmpline: print 
Got tmpline: \par
```

Then `\edef\totcontent{\totcontent, \mystyle{\tmpline}}` fails w:

```
! Use of \@pr@videpackage doesn't match its definition.
```

and `\g@addto@macro\totcontent{, \mystyle{\tmpline}}` produces:

```
totcontent is: , \texttt {\par }, \texttt {\par }, \texttt {\par }, \texttt {\par }, \texttt {\par }, \texttt {\par }.
```

... which is still not what I wanted...

Comment: `\read\myread to \tmpline`  will yield the `StrGobble`... stuff unnecessary

Comment: `\readline` is the wrong tool, use `\read`.

Comment: Many thanks, @ChristianHupfer and @egreg - I changed the example so it uses multi words per line; and indeed `\read` reads the whole line without LF (but the empty line at end is shown as `\par`), and does make StrGobble redundant. Still, that doesn't solve my problem: the `\edef` concat with `\mystyle{\tmpline}` then fails with `! Use of \@pr@videpackage doesn't match its definition.`; and the `\g@addto@macro` produces `\texttt {\par }, \texttt {\par }, ...`.

Comment: One problem is, that `\texttt` is not expandable, as far as I know

Comment: Thanks, @ChristianHupfer: that is actually what I was counting on: I didn't use `\edef` because I want to expand - I used it because it was the only method I know of concatenation. What I want to achieve is to get a command as if I verbatim wrote e.g. `\def\tst{\texttt{something here}, \texttt{and else}}`, and then use `\tst` in the document to be typeset - except that here it should be the result of concatenation of lines of file input as shown in MWE. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

The usual problem are the end of lines. You *don't* want `\readline`, but the normal `\read`.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.txt}
some more
words in
here so as
to eventually
print
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newread\myread
\makeatletter
\def\strip@final@space{\expandafter\strip@final@sp@ce\@tempa\strip@final@sp@ce}
\def\strip@final@sp@ce#1 \strip@final@sp@ce{\def\@tempa{#1}}
\def\a@par{\par}
\toks@={}
\openin\myread=\jobname.txt
\@whilesw\unless\ifeof\myread\fi{%
  \read\myread to \@tempa
  \typeout{Got tmpline: \@tempa}%
  \ifx\@tempa\a@par
  \else
    \strip@final@space
    \toks@=\expandafter{\the\expandafter\toks@\expandafter\texttt\expandafter{\@tempa}, }%
  \fi
}
\edef\totcontent{\the\toks@}
\closein\myread
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\typeout{totcontent is: \totcontent.}

I got this: \totcontent.

\end{document}
```

This is the output in the log file

```
totcontent is: \texttt {some more}, \texttt {words in}, \texttt {here so as}, \
texttt {to eventually}, \texttt {print}, .
```

Note that `\@tempa` will never be empty; an empty line or the final empty line will make `\@tempa` to expand to `\par`.

A simpler approach with `expl3`:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.txt}
some more
words in
here so as
to eventually
print
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_sdaau_lines_seq
\tl_new:N \l_sdaau_totcontent_tl
\ior_new:N \sdaau_read_stream
\ior_open:Nn \sdaau_read_stream { \c_job_name_tl.txt }
\ior_map_inline:Nn \sdaau_read_stream
 {
  %\msg_term:n {Got~line:~|#1|} % uncomment for debugging
  \seq_put_right:Nn \l_sdaau_lines_seq { \texttt { #1 } }
 }
\tl_set:Nx \l_sdaau_totcontent_tl { \seq_use:Nn \l_sdaau_lines_seq { ,~ } }

\tl_set_eq:NN \totcontent \l_sdaau_totcontent_tl
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\typeout{totcontent is: \totcontent.}

I got this: \totcontent.

\end{document}
```

The output is

```
totcontent is: \texttt {somemore}, \texttt {wordsin}, \texttt {heresoas}, \text
tt {toeventually}, \texttt {print}.
```

Note that there's no trailing comma.

If you plan to have blank lines in the file, then change the line

```
  \seq_put_right:Nn \l_sdaau_lines_seq { \texttt { #1 } }
```

into

```
  \tl_if_blank:nF { #1 }
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l_sdaau_lines_seq { \texttt { #1 } }
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\addto` macro by the following way:

```
\long\def\addto#1#2{\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1#2}}
\def\addtolist#1{\global\addto\totcontent{, \texttt{#1}}}

\newread\infile
\openin\infile=test-2.txt
\bgroup
  \endlinechar=-1 \gdef\totcontent{}%
  \loop
    \unless\ifeof\infile
       \read\infile to\tmp
       \ifx\tmp\empty \else \expandafter\addtolist\expandafter{\tmp}\fi
       \repeat
\egroup

\message{totcontent is: \meaning\totcontent}
```

The terminal prints:

```
totcontent is: macro:->, \texttt {some more}, \texttt {words in}, \texttt {here
 so as}, \texttt {to eventually}, \texttt {print}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got at least a working version - though I cannot say I understand what is going on; so a more erudite answer would still be appreciated. But after some messing about, I got a "two-step" approach with call to `\protected@edef` to work. Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents} % tlmgr install filecontents

\begin{filecontents*}{test-2.txt}
some more
words in
here so as
to eventually
print
\end{filecontents*}

\def\totcontent{}
\def\mystyle#1{\texttt{#1}}

\def\tst{\texttt{something here}, \texttt{and else}}

\newread\myread
\makeatletter
\immediate\openin\myread=test-2.txt
\@whilesw\unless\ifeof\myread\fi{%
  \read\myread to \tmpline %
  \typeout{Got tmpline: \tmpline} %
  %\ifx\tmpline\par % does NOT work if \tmpline is \par!
  \if\tmpline\par % does work if \tmpline is \par!
    \typeout{PAR} %
  \else %
    %\edef\mytmp{\par} \typeout{1: -\mytmp-}      % dbg
    %\edef\mytmp{\tmpline} \typeout{2: -\mytmp-}  % dbg
    \protected@edef\mytmp{\mystyle{\tmpline}} %
    \typeout{mytmp: \mytmp} %
    \protected@edef\totcontent{\totcontent, \mytmp}
  \fi %
}
\immediate\closein\myread
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\typeout{totcontent is: \totcontent.}

I had this: \tst;

I got this: \totcontent.

\end{document}
```

This produces in terminal printout:

```
Got tmpline: some more 
mytmp: \texttt {some more }
Got tmpline: words in 
mytmp: \texttt {words in }
Got tmpline: here so as 
mytmp: \texttt {here so as }
Got tmpline: to eventually 
mytmp: \texttt {to eventually }
Got tmpline: print 
mytmp: \texttt {print }
Got tmpline: \par 
PAR

totcontent is: , \texttt {some more }, \texttt {words in }, \texttt {here so as
 }, \texttt {to eventually }, \texttt {print }.
```

... and `\totcontent` is typeset as you'd expect, with right fonts and everything; which is what I originally wanted.